# Clear UITextfield Data when coming to that page again iphone

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have some dynamically allocated texfields and in which i am entering the text,

Now i have got two problems here 
1) After 2-3 button clicks, i mean changing the views and coming back to the same view than the data is not being removed from the textfield the previous data in the textfield is being present.
the code i have tried with are

```
    answerTextField.text = @"";
    answerTextField.text = nil;
```

2) I am unable to delete the textfield data in which i am appending the data that is coming from the textfield.text

```
      -(void) keyPressed: (NSNotification*) notification { 
if ([[[notification object]text] isEqualToString:@" "])
{
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:nextTag];
    textField.text = @"";
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    nextTag = textField.tag;
}
else
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object: nil];

    NSLog(@"TextField tag value :%d",tagCount);
    NSLog(@"TextField next tagg tag value :%d",nextTag);

    if (tagCount == nextTag+1) 
    {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:nextTag];
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        NSLog(@"append string :%@",appendString);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"TextField nexttag value before :%d",nextTag);

        nextTag = nextTag + 1;
        NSLog(@"Letter is%@",[[notification object]text]);

        str= [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[[notification object]text]];
        NSLog(@"TextField String :%@",str);

        NSLog(@"TextField nexttag value after :%d",nextTag);

        [appendString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str]];
        NSLog(@"Content in MutableString: %@",appendString);
    }

    NSLog(@"The tags in keypressed:%d",nextTag);
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:nextTag];
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
// For inserting Spaces taken from array.    
if(tagCount+300 == nextTag)
{
    for (int m=0  ; m< [intArray count]; m++) 
    {
        [appendString insertString:@" " atIndex:[[intArray objectAtIndex:m]intValue]];
        NSLog(@"FinalString : %@",appendString);
    }
}
```

}

Edited: The textfield data that i am storing is being made nil, but the on the textfield the data is being remained it is not being removed, for the textfield i have added a background image, do not know whether it makes any difference or not, i am attaching the code for it:

```
    UIImageView *myView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"text_line.png"]];
                myView.center = CGPointMake(5, 27);                     
                [letterField insertSubview:myView atIndex:0];// mgViewTitleBackGround is image
                [myView release];
```

Comment: What are you doing when in `viewWillDisappear:` and `viewWillAppear:`? It sound like you should remove the text in either of those. You could also look at `clearsOnBeginEditing` on the UITextField if that gives you the behavior that you are looking for.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist : i haven't done anything, See i have taken only one viewcontroller and added views.

Answer (score 2):

To clear text field do this code in viewWillAppear:

```
  NSArray *arraysubViews = [self.view subViews];

  for(UIView *subView in arraysubViews){

      if([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
          // if(subView.tag == MY_TEXT_VIEW_TAG)
           (UITextField *)subView.text = @"";
       }
   }
```

This will remove the `text` in every UITextField in your view. If you need to clear some textfields only, uncomment the code; which will check against `tag` value

**EDIT**

```
  NSArray *arraysubViews = [self.view subviews];

  for(UIView *subView in arraysubViews){

      if([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
          // if(subView.tag == MY_TEXT_VIEW_TAG)
          UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)subView;
          textField.text = @"";
       }
   }
```

UIView does not have a `subViews` method. It is `subViews` instead.

Comment: i have tried with this piece of code that u have given, the app is getting crashed saying  : -[UIView subViews]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xff13370,    
See i have taken only one viewcontroller and added views.

Comment: try to set a tag in your textFields, and then give a condition to met those tag before you set your subView text. (u might want to try [subView setText:@""] instead of (UITextField *)subView.text = @""

Comment: @rakeshNS: Tried with that code too, still the same problem, can u say me, what should i replace for subView.text, as it is giving me error over there.

Comment: @sailaja Ok, dont copy paste the above code, from your comment it is clear that there is no method called subViews, it should be subviews. So change code like this  NSArray *arraysubViews = [self.view subviews]; Sure you will free from error. For safety you can do like UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)subView; textField.text = @""; instead of writing (UITextField *)subView.text = @"";

Comment: @rakeshNS: Will give it a try and will let u know.